# Gitlab private runner lasts more than an hour against 9 minutes on my local computer

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I have set a runner on my server. In the beginning, it took 3 minutes to run the project. Since few days, it takes more than one hour to execute the same project.
I really don't understand what is happening.
I'm using the latest version on gitlab runner.

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            62G        982M         59G         63M        1,8G         60G
Swap:          1,0G          0B        1,0G

$ df -h
Sys. de fichiers Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
udev                32G       0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs              6,3G     10M  6,3G   1% /run
/dev/md3            20G    6,5G   12G  36% /
tmpfs               32G    4,0K   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs              5,0M       0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs               32G       0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md2           487M     67M  392M  15% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1     510M    152K  510M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/md4           392G     16G  357G   5% /home
```

$ cat /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml :

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "xxxxxx"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "xxxxxx"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "php:7.1"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

$ journalctl -u gitlab-runner -f

```
Checking for jobs... received                       job=340331549 repo_url=https://gitlab.com/xxxx/xxxx.git runner=xxxx
Checking for jobs... received                       job=340331549 repo_url=https://gitlab.com/xxxx/xxxx.git runner=xxxx
ERROR: Could not create cache adapter               error=cache factory not found: factory for cache adapter "" was not registered
ERROR: Could not create cache adapter               error=cache factory not found: factory for cache adapter "" was not registered
WARNING: Job failed: execution took longer than 1h0m0s seconds  duration=1h0m0.154502055s job=340331549 project=123456 runner=xxxx
WARNING: Job failed: execution took longer than 1h0m0s seconds  duration=1h0m0.154502055s job=340331549 project=123456 runner=xxxx
WARNING: Failed to process runner                   builds=0 error=execution took longer than 1h0m0s seconds executor=docker runner=xxxx
WARNING: Failed to process runner                   builds=0 error=execution took longer than 1h0m0s seconds executor=docker runner=xxxx
```

gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: php:7.1
cache:
  untracked: true
  paths:
    - vendor/
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
before_script:
  - bash ci/docker_install.sh > /dev/null
test:
  script:
  - vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration tests/phpunit.xml --coverage-text --colors=never
variables:
  APP_ENV: "testing"
  FIREBIRD: "/opt/firebird"
```

Comment: This question will get many different answers. What did you do already to find out the source of this issue? 
Check free memory and disk space.

Did the project grow in dependencies? Do you have caches?

Network latencies for downloading stuff?

Is something else running on this server?

Comment: I've ran gitlab-runner verify to check if something wrong, but it seems ok. I confess that I don't where to search...

Comment: Are you able to add the configuration of your gitlab runner? At least, you have enough memory. So I think it's not a resource problem. Cpu will have enough add well, I think.

Comment: Yeah, my server has enough memory and CPU. The web apps that are working on it don't consume lot of resources. I've pasted the content of the config from /etc

Comment: Simple configuration. Looks fine to me.

Any log entries? When you build the app, what takes the most time currently? What's inside the volume cache?

Comment: phpunit tests are taking lot of time while on my computer it takes 9 minutes max. Last week on the server these test took about 6 minutes to achieve, that's why it's really weird. The cache contains the vendor dir

Comment: Do you have any output of your gitlab runner on build time? Can you see, what does it take so long?

Otherwise we could do some try and error, remove the vendor directory in the cache directory and see, if the build works better.

Comment: I've added the job logs, there is an error for cache, maybe this .... I'm looking for why I have this error... Dutring the tests, I don't have any log in the pipeline console.

Comment: I have commented out the runners.cache part in the config.toml file, so the error disapear but duration problem persist

Comment: I just ran a ne pipeline and now the job took 29 minutes

Comment: 29 minutes is still a lot. Or was it because the cache directory was empty?